# Is there an efficient way to overwrite a string at index with another string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I'm trying to overwrite a string with another string (from an index), in Python 3.x. I want to know if there is already a String method that can already do this or if there is an efficient way to do this.

I know the easiest way to achieve this would be to write a loop that starts at an index and then replaces each character of string a with string b (shown in code below).

```py
def func(a, b, index):
    newStr = list(a)
    for i in range(index, index+len(b)):
        if i < len(a):
            newStr[i] = b[i-index]
        else:
            newStr.append(b[i-index])
    return ''.join(newStr)
```

If I have two strings string: 
`a = '012345678'` and `b = 'abcde'`

And the index set as `6`, then the expected output from the function should be: `'012345abcde'`.

Comment: do you know slicing? `a[:6] + b`

Comment: Note that strings in Python are immutable. You *cannot* overwrite them. But you can *combine* (parts of) strings into a new string, which is what skymon's answer does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
def func(a, b, index):
    return a[:index] + b
```